# Creation / registration new user with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm learning and developing Restful api as a backend for my future android application. And I use spring framework. I use spring security to restrict access to some resources.
I have UserController with method **create(params..)** which should create new user.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    private UserService userService;
    private CreateFormValidator createFormValidator;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, CreateFormValidator createFormValidator) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.createFormValidator = createFormValidator;
    }
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(createFormValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String create(@RequestBody @Valid CreateForm createForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "user_create";
        }
        try {
            userService.create(createForm);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            bindingResult.reject("username.exists", "Username already exists");
            return "user_create";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

And configuration for security, for now I specify here only that I want "user/create/" is permitted for all.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("user/create").permitAll();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

But when I test it and do POST on "user/create" with json body

```
{
  "username" : "name",
  "password" : "1234",
  "repeatedPassword" : "1234"
}
```

i'm getting:

> "error": "Forbidden" "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found
>   on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'."

Can you explain me why it s forbidden when in configure class there is permitAll access for this url? And how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add csrf token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/

if you're using rest client, include X-CSRF-TOKEN to request header. You'll  get csrf token value from one of your get requests to your service.

or alternatively try following:

```
{
  "username" : "name",
  "password" : "1234",
  "repeatedPassword" : "1234",
  "_csrf" : "token value"
}
```